# What does np.cumsum(0) do?

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
np.cumsum(a)
```

I know the output of the above is array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21]) which displays the cumulative sums of the array a.

However, I have trouble understand the following. what does cumsum(0) do?

```
np.random.randn(365).cumsum(0)
```

Comment: Please read the manual before asking questions. The answer is given there. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html

Comment: The manual doesn't deal with that. I know the manual very well. Your comment does not help at all.

Comment: I did not mean to insult you, I am only trying to help to keep SO tidy and in order. It is a good habit to read manuals before asking questions, to avoid asking the obvious. To address why I wrote what I wrote: you know that in numpy `np.cumsum(a, 0) == a.cumsum(0)`. If you then open the help, it covers **exactly** that example: `>>> np.cumsum(a,axis=0)      # sum over rows for each of the 3 columns`

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I did not ask about how to "open the help". I know how to open the help. As a matter of fact, it doesn't mention anything about a.cumsum(0) == np.cumsum(a, axis=0).

Comment: Really, don't take it personally, it is great you are asking questions. It is only that your example is one of the few that is exactly worked out in the quite short help. But you apparently did not know that `np.cumsum(a, 0) == a.cumsum(0)` is the same. Therefore, I can recommend you this read: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/whatisnumpy.html. Read the last paragraph, it is quite a helpful first introduction into numpy's organization and approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't about `numpy.cumsum(0)`

Here, `0` is the *axis* parameter of the `cumsum` *method* of the array *object* defined by `np.random.randn(365)`. It can be omitted in this case (default is `None` to flatten the array, but array is already flat here)

`np.cumsum` is a function taking the array as first argument, whereas in the second example `cumsum` is a method of the array (both do the same computation, the first one having no axis, it flattens in the process)

Answer (score 0):

```
df=np.random.randn(10)
print(df)
print(df.cumsum(0))
```

Output:

```
[-1.09  1.    0.28 -1.51 -0.58  1.65 -2.43 -0.43  1.27 -0.87]
[-1.09 -0.09  0.19 -1.31 -1.89 -0.24 -2.67 -3.09 -1.83 -2.7 ]
```

I hope you see how it works.
0 in cumsum(0) means that is adding over axis=0. In this case the single axis you have.